# How to convert C code to Fault tree through AST ？

Tags: antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a set of C codes, and I want to convert C codes into a fault tree,I've tried generate AST by Antlr,but I have no idea about the next step.There are many ways to do this including yacc antlr DMS lex, but none of them get me what I want.AST is a necessary way to generate fault tree?

```
#include "Sta.h"
void Sta(sta *localP)
{
  UNSIGNED8 Switch;
  if (!wl_gul) {
    if (!sdi) {
      if (!qdi) {
        Switch= localP->Constant1;
      } else {
        Switch = localP->Constant2;
      }
    } else {
      Switch= localP->Constant3;
    }
  } else {
    Switch= localP->Constant4;
  }

  stag_gul = Switch;
}
```

Comment: What's a fault tree?

Comment: I think the link can answer you.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault_tree_analysis

Comment: Thanks, however I think this question is too broad and lacks a lot of information. You should break your big problem into smaller pieces, try to implement them and ask specific questions about your implementation.

Comment: Your Wikipedia article describes how to build a fault tree using primitive events/faults.    I don't understand how you consider generating a fault tree from a C program...  what are the primitive events?  A memory read failing?   Why don't you exhibit a C program for which you have a fault tree (even if manually constructed) so that we can understand your intent?